# Using a slider bar to auto refresh a part of page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

So I am trying to use a slider bar to control how soon the page should be refreshed. After checking the box, it should start auto refreshing, after checking it off, it should stop auto-refreshing.

this is my current jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z68mR/19/

Two problems: why does the sliding the bar does not change the value? I set it to 10 at the start, it displays 10 but does not change when I drag it around.

Is the way I am setting up the setInterval correct?

```
function refresh(time){
        refreshIntervalId = setInterval(
            function ()
                    {
                    // things to do...
                    }, parseInt(time*1000));    
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've gone ahead and updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z68mR/21/)

The first issue was your showValue function was not defined on the global window object.

```
window.showValue = showValue;
```

Next we need to define your `refreshIntervalId` variable outside of any functions so that it always refers to the same object.

Lastly we clear the old interval every time we enter a new one

```
clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
refreshIntervalId = setInterval(
                function ()
                {
                $("#area").text("Refreshed").fadeIn(300).fadeOut(300).fadeIn(300).fadeOut(300);
                }, parseInt(time*1000));
```